# WebAPI postman not calling Post

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have a post on a controller that I can not call with post, and I can not see what I have done wrong.

```
 [RoutePrefix("api/camps")]
 public class CampsController : ApiController

  [Route()]
  public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get()
  {
      //Return list
  }


  [Route()]
  public IHttpActionResult Post(object model)
  {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
```

When I run the application in visual studio and call post in Postman with 
http://localhost:6600/api/camps 
I get the expected list returned, and when putting in break points everything gets hit, that I would expect.

When I call Post with http://localhost:6600/api/camps with in Body and Raw in postman I have entered.

```
{

    "Name": "Mr A",
}
```

I get the post method hit but the model of type object is blank.
If I change the model to be of type camp the model it has every property being null.
I have changed all the case, and added and removed double and singe quotes.

My WebApiConfig

```
 public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {     

        //Changes names on result to be camel case not what they are in the model.
        config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        //For binding to models when passing in data
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/plain"));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create one class with your desired properties, something like below:

```
public class Your_Class
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        //...Your other properties if any

    }
```

Now in your API use this model class as a parameter.

```
  [Route()]
  public IHttpActionResult Post(Your_Class model)
  {
       throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
```

**UPDATE**

For other people who still are facing this issue, please make sure to set `Content-Type` as `application/json` in `header` section of post request in postman before sending the request.

Comment: I said in the question "If I change the model to be of type camp the model it has every property being null."

Comment: try setting headers to  Content-Type as application/json in postman before sending the request.

Comment: that was the answer, thanks for that, if you want to post it, I will mark it as the answer

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I have updated the answer.